# jquery-template checkbox oncheck

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, jquery-templates

I have this template checkbox here. I need to call in my jquery whenever it is clicked. How would I do that I'm new to templates.

```
 script id="listTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
<div class="task_block clearfix modalRow">
<input type="checkbox" class="itemLinked" name="link" data-itemid="${ItemId}" data-itemtype="${ItemType}" data-linkid="${Id}" {{if IsLinked}}checked="checked"{{/if}}>
<div class="left mls">
```

this is what I have in my jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=link]").change(function () {
        alert("test");
    });

});
```

Comment: From the doc: _"value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string."_

Comment: Try `on()` with delegation instead: `$(document).on('change', 'input[name="link"]', function() { ... });`

Comment: i tried the on one first but like this  $("input[name=link]".on("change",function(){ and neither way seems to be working correctly..

Comment: Did you try how I suggested? Because that's different from what you posted. Are there any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: i tried both it says it doenst support property or method 'on'
 $(document).on('change', 'input[name=link]', function () {
        alert('test');
    });

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.6.2  and actually i aslo have this in my jquery    var limit = 5, dir = ' Desc', sort = 'Created', index = 0, autoscroll = false;
    function getDataUrl(index, action) {        
        return '/Team/Linking/ListItemLinks/@Model.ItemId/?type=@Model.ItemType';
        
    }

Comment: `on()` was introduced in 1.7. I would recommend upgrading, but if you can't, try `live()` instead of `on()`

Answer (score 0):

In versions of jQuery prior to 1.7 you can use `live()` to attach an event to dynamically added elements.

For example:

```
$('input[name=link]').live('change', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

See a working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/coderdude/GyCCF/